# Neo4j cypher transform query to c#

Tags: c#, cypher

I need to transform this query to use with the graphclient inside c#:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r*2..10]-(m)
WHERE n.Id = 94 and m.Id = 94
AND NONE (node IN NODES(p) WHERE SIZE(
                FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE node = x AND x.Id <> 94)
        ) > 1
    )
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(p)| n.Id) AS Paths, length(p), r
order by length(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

the closest solution that I could put together is:

```
    var results = neoDB.Cypher
    .Match("p=(n:JUNCTIONS)-[r*2..10]-(m:JUNCTIONS)")
    .Where("n.Id={startNodeId} and m.Id={endNodeId}")
    .WithParam("startNodeId", 92)
    .WithParam("endNodeId", 92)
    .Return((p, n, m, r) => new
    {
        path = p.CollectAs<Neo4jClient.ApiModels.Cypher.PathsResult>(),
        node1 = n.As<cNode>(),
        node2 = m.As<cNode>(),
        Relation = r.As<IEnumerable<cNode>>()
    }).Results;
```

the filter for lengths greater than one was unnecessary, this solution is good for me